# Как заставить данный код записывать данные в базу данных?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql, aiogram

Произошла проблема - по непонятной мне причине, код не хочет записывать значение в базу данных. Концепция кода следующая - человек отправляет сообщение, и бот записывает его сообщение в базу данных. Если в коде произошла ошибка - пишется "ERR". Но бот при этапе отправки сообщения, просто не собирается отправлять данные в бд, даже не подает знаков отправки. Благодарен за любую помощь

Код:

```py
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="⚡️ ️Купить билет"))
async def with_pureee(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(" Загружаем данные")
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    back = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    buttons = ["⚡️ Назад"]
    back.add(*buttons)
    await message.answer("❗️ Пожалуйста, введите ваше ФИО. Оно может быть сверено с вашим паспортом в целях безопасности", reply_markup=back)
    @dp.message_handler()
    async def names(message: types.Message):
        mes = message.text
        if mes == "⚡️ Назад":
            return
        else:
            try:
                conn = await aiomysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,
                                           user='root', password='', db='aiodb', loop=loop)
                cur = await conn.cursor()
                await cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name) values(msg)")
                await conn.commit()
                await cur.close()
            except Exception as e:
                @dp.message_handler()
                async def names(message: types.Message):
                    await message.answer("ERR")
```

Comment: await cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name) values(msg)")
______ Что делает эта строка? Что за msg, не вижу его нигде кроме как в этом месте? Какая конкретно ошибка выдаётся? Уберите на время трай/ексепт и добавьте к вопросу. И последний вопрос, какого черта у вас хендлер в хендлере? Чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вот так будет значительно лучше. Жду ответа на комментарий

```
class InputDataUser(StatesGroup):
    FIO = State()


@dp.message_handler(text="⚡️ ️Купить билет")
async def with_pureee(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(" Загружаем данные")
    back = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    buttons = ["⚡️ Назад"]
    back.add(*buttons)
    await message.answer(
        "❗️ Пожалуйста, введите ваше ФИО. Оно может быть сверено с вашим паспортом в целях безопасности",
        reply_markup=back
    )
    await InputDataUser.FIO.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=InputDataUser.FIO)
async def names(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    mes = message.text
    if mes == "⚡️ Назад":
        await state.finish()
        return
    
    try:
        conn = await aiomysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,
                                      user='root', password='', db='aiodb', loop=loop)
        cur = await conn.cursor()
        await cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name) values(msg)")
        await conn.commit()
        await cur.close()
        await state.finish()
    except Exception:
        await message.answer("ERR")
```

Comment: Приму ваше решение, спасибо. Но я уже тоже решил эту проблему, без использования FIO = State()

Comment: Но хотел бы понять, почему так плохо совать хенд в хенд

Comment: Как минимум в этом нет смысла, вы просто должны делать нормальные фильтры и условия для срабатывания хендлеров. Когда же вы суете их в другой хендлер, получается что порядок этих хендлеров меняется и меняется очень странно.